# Buffering an expression via property in LINQ (vs Lambda)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a large `select` expression to reuse in several classes. For the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle I have chosen to create a property that returns the `Expression` to the caller code

```
    protected virtual Expression<Func<SezioneJoin, QueryRow>> Select
    {
        get
        {
            return sj => new QueryRow
            {
                A01 = sj.A.A01,
                A01a = sj.A.A01a,
                A01b = sj.A.A01b,
                A02 = sj.A.A02,
                A03 = sj.A.A03,
                A11 = sj.A.A11,
                A12 = sj.A.A12,
                A12a = sj.A.A12a,
                A12b = sj.A.A12b,
                A12c = sj.A.A12c,
                A21 = sj.A.A21,
                A22 = sj.A.A22,
                ..............
                Lots of assignements
            };
        }
    }
```

Now I can successfully use the property if I do

```
var query = dataContext.entity.Join(...).Where(x => ...).Select(Select);
```

But the following will not compile:

```
       from SezioneJoin sj in (
               from A a in ...
               join D d in ... on new { ... } equals new { ... }

               where
                    d.D13 == "086" &&
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.A32) && a.A32 != "086"
               orderby a.A21
               orderby a.prog
               select new SezioneJoin{...})

       select Select
```

Error is

```
Unable to cast 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<DiagnosticoSite.Data.Query.SezioneJoin,DiagnosticoSite.Data.Query.QueryRow>>>' into 'System.Linq.IQueryable<DiagnosticoSite.Data.Query.QueryRow>'
```

I can understand that the LINQ syntax requires the body of the select statement to be the inner type of the `IQueryable` that it returns, so the compiler is fooled into returning a list of expressions. With the Lambda syntax, the expression is a parameter that is either compiled in-line or returned by some other method (even dynamically!).

I would like to ask if there is any way to circumvent this and avoid defining large `select` expressions inline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> protected virtual Expression> Select

I'd avoid using the names of any of the Linq-mapped methods (`Select`, `Where`, `GroupBy`, `OrderBy`, `OrderByDescending`) as member names. It works in this case, but when it causes problems by matching the definitions for those it can be confusing if you aren't in the habit of just not using those names unless you deliberately **want** to override Linq.

On a related note. Consider that:

```
from var item in source select item.Something
```

is equivalent to:

```
source.Select(item => item.Something);
```

Therefore:

```
from SezioneJoin sj in (/*…*/) select Select;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(/*…*/).Select(sj => Select);
```

That is, you arent' creating a query that executes the expression in `Select`, but one that returns the expression itself.

You should either just use the form `.Select(Select)` or use `select sj => (Select)(sj)` but that second one will (if I even have the parentheses correct to stop it clashing with `Queryable.Select`, I haven't tested that) call the `Select` property every time so is at best wasteful and at worse not going to be something a query provider can make use of, so it will fail with most linq-providers. In all, use the `.Select(Select)` form (and change the name).

(On a separate note, if you're going to buffer an expression, actually buffer it; create a private `Expression<Func<SezioneJoin, QueryRow>>` once and return it in the property's getter, rather than creating it every time).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743(v=vs.110).aspx) in place of last LINQ select statement:

```
var query = from SezioneJoin sj ... select new SezioneJoin{...});
var projection = query.Select(Select);
```

Comment: Important note that I suggest to use LINQ for whole query expect select statement. OP only mentions that he can use extension methods for whole query.

Comment: Anyway I still currently wrap the LINQ in parenthesis then issue Lambda